# How to make a full page header?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to replicate making a header like [this](https://mtthwnvk.exposure.so/southern-maine-13), but I'm not really sure how I would go about that. I started with making an image fill the whole screen, but I can't get it to look as good as the example I provided.

I've seen this exact kind of header [multiple times](http://paulstamatiou.com/photos/japan/japan-day-0/). I was wondering if there's some kind of library that makes it easier to make a header like that?

[Another example](https://medium.com/mother-jones/82864cfe3990)

The code that I have right now (HTML and css, I did not put it together like this in the actual file obviously):

```
<div class="cover">
<div class="filler">Text inside header</div>
</div>

.cover{
  background: url("../img/day1cover.jpg"); 
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
  box-shadow: inset 0px -120px 100px -10px rgba(0,0,0,0.7);
  position: relative;
  color: rgb(255,255,255);  
}

.filler{
  width:100%;
  height: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0;
}
```

Comment: Your code example is incomplete.  Where is .cover defined in the html?

Comment: Oops, screwed that up when editing/copying the original file to get this snippet. Edited.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This simple fiddle should get you on the right path :

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/tm2V3/11/)**

**EXPLANATION** :

To make the "header" use the whole page you need to set it to 100% width and height of the browser window. for that, you can use :

```
 html, body, .cover {
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
```

Then to make the image use the whole space availalble without cropping or loosing aspect ratio , you can sue the `background` CSS property like this :

```
.cover { 
  background: url(your_image.jpg) no-repeat center center; 
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

---

**EDIT**

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/tm2V3/13/)** with overlay on the header and header text at the bottom of the header.

---

**FULL CODE**
HTML :

```
<div class="cover">
    <div class="filler">Text inside header</div>
    <div class="overlay"></div>
</div>
<div id="content">
    ... SITE CONTENT ...
</div>
```

CSS :

```
html, body, .cover, #content, .overlay {
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
.cover {
    background: url("http://lorempixel.com/output/abstract-q-g-1152-839-1.jpg") no-repeat center center;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
    box-shadow: inset 0px -120px 100px -10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
    position: relative;
    color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
}
.filler {
    position:absolute;
    bottom:20px;
    left:0;
    width:100%;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0;
    z-index:2;
}
.overlay {
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    bottom:0;
    left:0;
    right:0;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    z-index:1;
}
#content {
    padding:100px;
    background: url("http://lorempixel.com/output/city-q-g-1152-839-4.jpg");
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I tried using this before, but I couldnt get the text to the bottom of the div. I also couldn't figure out how to get the overlay as in the examples. Thanks for the input!

Comment: @user1910584 you want the header text to be at teh bottom like this? http://jsfiddle.net/tm2V3/7/ and what do you mean by "overlay"?

Comment: How did you do that so fast... That's what I wanted. If you look at [this example](https://mtthwnvk.exposure.so/southern-maine-13), you can disable the overlay. That's the overlay that I want.

Comment: @user1910584 happy I could help ;) but I still don't understand the overlay, part do you mean that the text disapears when you scroll down?

Comment: When you load the image, the image fills the browser. If you hover over the bottom left part of that image, you see an eye icon. If you click that icon, you can toggle the overlay. The overlay that you can toggle is what I am talking about :)

Comment: @user1910584 Ah ok I'll see what I can do about that

Comment: You're my hero. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

The site you provided to is responsive. 
You can use http://getbootstrap.com/ framework to achieve what you wish to do

Also if you get inspierd by sites you find on the internet you can inspect them and see how they are built by using firebug(firefox), or press F12 when in chrome/IE and you will see the built in dev-tool that alowws you to debug scripts, inspect html and alot more. [Check out firebug](https://addons.mozilla.org/sv-se/firefox/addon/firebug/)

Comment: It's not the responsive part of the site that I want to achieve; It's the fullscreen header + animated arrow + overlay that I want. Any way to do that?

Answer (score 0):

The effect those pages use is called Parallax. Check [this](http://smashinghub.com/7-jquery-parallax-and-scrolling-effect-plugins.htm). There are many different ones, I'm sure you will find one that suits you.

Here is the list for jQuery: https://plugins.jquery.com/tag/parallax/

Comment: It's not the parallax that I want to achieve; It's the fullscreen header with an animated arrow and overlay that I want.

Comment: I understand, but most of them have fullscreen headers and animations. Or do you want the exact as on that page?

Comment: Yes. it doesn't have to be exactly the same, but I do want to make it look like the examples I have in the OP.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly you want a header that is full screen on any screen size and a text at the bottom and the arrow.

Here is a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HpL2H/).

You could use Javascript/jQuery to get the height of the user's screen and apply that to the height of you header.

Something like this:

```
/* Get browser height */
var browserHeight = $(window).height();

$("header").css("height", browserHeight);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="cover">
<div class="filler">Text inside header</div>
</div>
```

css

```
.cover{
  background: url("../img/day1cover.jpg"); 
  background-attachment: fixed;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: 50% 50%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  //your css

  box-shadow: inset 0px -120px 100px -10px rgba(0,0,0,0.7);
  //position: relative; none
  color: rgb(255,255,255);  
}

.filler{
  width:100%;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try to use this solution**:
http://css-tricks.com/perfect-full-page-background-image/

```
.selector { 
  background: url(images/bg.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed; 
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

Works in:

- Safari 3+
- Chrome Whatever+
- IE 9+
- Opera 10+ (Opera 9.5 supported background-size but not the keywords)
- Firefox 3.6+ (Firefox 4 supports non-vendor prefixed version)

and olso for IE

```
.selector {
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(src='.myBackground.jpg', sizingMethod='scale');
    -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(src='myBackground.jpg', sizingMethod='scale')";
}
```

Olso:

There is a **`One Page Scroll`** plugin on jQuery,
it might be useful in your case.
**URL**: http://www.thepetedesign.com/demos/onepage_scroll_demo.html